# Is there an existing concept for handling permission in a vaadin JPAContainer?

Tags: permissions, vaadin

I have a vaadin application using JPAContainer an want to implement some sort of access control. The container should filter all entities that the user is not allowed to read and restricts modification to those users explicitly allowed.

My question is now if there is an existing solution to help implementing this. I searched for it and didn't find anything. Not even a discussion or description of a concept. So i assume the answer is "No" and I'm basically asking to provide a better search result for the next one looking for this.

Nevertheless would I be happy if someone points me to something that helps me implementing this properly.

Thanks 
Raffael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a thing in jpacontainer nor in vaadin.

Vaadin applications are secure and safe if say, the "Edit" or "delete" button is not visible, there is no way to hack it. Or you can have the button disabled only, but do not attach a click listener to it if the user has no permission to do it.